# Is there any way to make component as singleton in angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I need to make component as a single ton so anywhere in application i can use it with out initialize it again.

how can do this ?

Comment: How do you intialize components ?

Comment: Would an Injectable also work in your case or does it need to be a Component?

Comment: Creating a component on the fly can be done using viewcontainer. However, There are inherent disadvantages of doing that. You don't want a component sharing same properties across multiple renders. I am unsure if that is even accommodated as a use case. I have not done it. But what are you trying to achieve? What's the purpose?

Comment: I have one component with some html in it when component load then i do some DOM manipulation so when component need anywhere in application then no need to do it again. so need to persist this component and reuse it again.

Comment: another idea: create a service, and in the ngOnInit of the component use the variables store in the service to initialize the component

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make it with a static field, assign first instance to it in constructor and throw if it's already assigned (somebody tried to instantiate a second copy). Then you can access static field to get access to the instance anywhere. Roughly something like this:

```
export class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        if (MyClass.instance) {
            throw('Already instantiated');
        }

        MyClass.instance = this;
    }

    static instance: MyClass;
}
```

And then in any other component/service you can access `MyClass.instance`.

Comment: this code can preserve component instance now how can i re render it again in some other component ?

Comment: That wouldn't be singleton now, wouldn't it? :) If you do not need a singleton and just need to keep track of instances — use some singleton service that would store them for you.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hacky idea. The only reason to make a component a singleton is so that data is not lost and there are ways of preserving data without making the component a singleton. For example, store the data in a singleton service and then each time the component is initialised, grab the data from the singleton service. Or use a store solution such as ngrx.

Using the new:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

syntax, the service automatically becomes a singleton and is loaded on demand, no need to add it to a providers array. Which makes working with singleton services super easy.

Comment: Agree with your point if only data need to preserve. I need to preserve html as well.

Comment: In the initialisation, your data should drive your HTML using the likes of *ngFor or even (if absolutely necessary) using jQuery or an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Write following code in component that you need to make it singleton.
Here shared service is initialized at root level so it has one instance all over the application.

```
constructor(public sharedService: SharedService) {
    if (!this.sharedService.myComponent) {
        this.sharedService.myComponent = this;
    } else {
        Object.assign(this, this.sharedService.myComponent);
    }
}
```